# NHibernate - one-to-many just not working with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate

**TL;DR;**
`NHibernate` reverse relationship is working on `Azure-SQL` and `MSSQL2012` but not with `SQLite`

**Description:**
I am currently Unittesting my Asp.Net MVC App and set up my Unittest with `FluentMigrator` on SQLite.

After creating the Database I set up some base entries I need.
One of those is a Product.
A `Product` has many `ProductSuppliers` and a `ProductSupplier` has many `ProductSupplierPrices`

```
public class Product
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    //more properties
    public virtual IList<ProductSupplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    //more properties
}

public class ProductSupplier 
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ProductSupplierPrice> Prices { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSupplierPrice : IHaveId
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductSupplier ProductSupplier { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal FromAmount { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

**Setup:**

1. Create Supplier
2. Create Product
3. Create ProductSupplier
4. Create ProductSupplierPrice

**Test:**

```
Product product = this.session.Load<Product>((long)1);
ProductSupplier productSupplier = product.Suppliers.First(); //<-- Suppliers are null; therefore throws an exception
```

If I load them seperately to check the relationships:

```
productSupplierPrice.ProductSupplier <--- Correct Supplier

productSupplier.Prices <-- Null 
productSupplier.Product <-- Product with Id 1

product.Suppliers <-- Null
```

So to me it seems, that the many-to-one direction works correctely, but the one-to-many (reverse relation) is not working.

**The Problem exists only in my Unittest (SQLite) the App itself runs on `Azure-SQL` and is working fine.**

**EDIT:**
Mappings with FluentnHibernate

```
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.Suppliers).Inverse().Cascade.DeleteOrphan().BatchSize(20);
       //many more mappings
    }
}

public ProductSupplierMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    References(x => x.Product);
    References(x => x.Supplier);
    Map(x => x.IsMainSupplier);
    Map(x => x.SupplierProductNumber);
    Map(x => x.CopperSurcharge);
    HasMany(x => x.Prices).Inverse().Cascade.DeleteOrphan().BatchSize(20);
}

public ProductSupplierPriceMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    References(x => x.ProductSupplier);
    Map(x => x.FromAmount);
    Map(x => x.Price);
}
```

**Edit2 - Creating the DB-Entries:**

```
Product product = new Product()
{
    Type = ProductType.Purchase,
    Dispatcher = session.Load<Employee>(employeeId),
    Number = "100.10-1000",
    Name = "Testproduct",
    //Lots of Properties
    Suppliers =  new List<ProductSupplier>()
};
session.SaveOrUpdate(product);

ProductSupplier productSupplier = new ProductSupplier()
{
    Product = product,
    Supplier = session.Load<Supplier>((long)1),
    IsMainSupplier = true,
    SupplierProductNumber = "Artikel123456",
    CopperSurcharge = CopperSurchargeType.DEL700,
    Prices = new List<ProductSupplierPrice>()
};
session.Save(productSupplier);

ProductSupplierPrice productSupplierPrice = new ProductSupplierPrice()
{
    ProductSupplier = productSupplier,
    FromAmount = 1,
    Price = 5
};
session.Save(productSupplierPrice);
```

**EDIT 3.1:**

```
public static ISession InitializeDatabase()
{
    NHibernateSessionHolder.CreateSessionFactory();
    session = NHibernateSessionHolder.OpenSession();
    CreateBaseEntries(); //Creates Employees, Supplier, Customer etc
    return session;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the code / mapping XML to show how classes are mapped?

Comment: I updated my Question accordingly

Comment: IIRC, the IList collection must have a default value set via either constructor OR a backing field which is assigned an empty list.

Comment: You mean in my Model? My model should be fine, because it works with other databases.

Comment: Yes. I think I witnessed that issue too long time ago and found this to be the only solution.

Comment: I have added empty Lists to my entry creation, still no change.
Also added the whole creation of the DB entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95246/discussion-between-vijay-gill-and-altoyr).

Comment: I have added a zip file, with the project!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the [Ayende's article](http://ayende.com/blog/3983/nhibernate-unit-testing) you need to clear the session between insert/update and querying:

```
session.Clear();
```

Seems to be a session management, I'm not sure why the session should be clean, but the session is providing your original instance (the same you provided for saving, stored on the session cache) instead a proxy for lazy-loading.

```
private long CreatePurchaseOrder()
{
    session.Clear();

    var product = this.session.Load<Product>((long)1);
    var productSupplier = product.Suppliers.First();
    var productSupplierPrice = productSupplier.Prices.First();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Great answer!!! I did not notice this on my phone app and posted mine too which is similar to yours!!! My +1 vote for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry for late reply**

In your unit test, you are using same session for creating and fetching entities. This is not right as subsequent fetch returns entities from first level cache which do not have their graph set up properly.

So....either use different sessions **OR** as a quick fix, I have added "session.Clear()" in the method "InitializeDatabase()" of "DatabaseSetUpHelper". Clearing the session clears first level cache and force NH to fetch data from DB again and the resulting entities have their graph set up properly.

```
    public static ISession InitializeDatabase()
    {
        NHibernateSessionHolder.CreateSessionFactory();
        session = NHibernateSessionHolder.OpenSession();
        CreateBaseEntries();
        session.Clear(); // notice this!!! this clears first level cache of session, thus forcing fetching of data from DB
        return session;
    }
```

**Note:** My quick-fix is not final solution, it is there just show how session behaves. In proper solution, you must use different sessions.